# Building a Mac/PC Network in a Dorm with Network Restrictions

Tags: windows-xp, networking, osx-snow-leopard

I have been a Windows XP user for the last few years, but I recently bought a 15'' MacBook Pro for research purposes. I would like to set up a no-hassle Mac/PC Network at home so that I can access the internet on both computers and hardware between computers (i.e. a harddrive, or a mouse/keyboard with [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/)).

Unfortunately, I live in a dorm with silly network restrictions so a solution is not straightforward. In particular:

- The dorm has a wired and wireless network, both which provide an internet connection.
- The wired network provides way faster internet (download speeds of 15 MB/s vs. 2 MB/s on wireless), so I would like to somehow exploit this, at least on my PC for Bittorrent :)
- Multiple devices can connect to the wireless network, but cannot "see" each other on the network (so software like Synergy would not work).
- Only 1 MAC address can connect to the wired network at a time.

Ideally I would just connect a wireless router to the wired network and then have both the Mac and the PC on that, but the 1 MAC address restriction will not allow the both computer to access the internet simultaneously. I cannot think of a way to bypass this restriction (though I'm not network savvy), so I am planning to create a private no-internet network to allow the devices to see each other and share hardware.

Here are some thoughts. I would appreciate any feedback at all!

**If I build a private wireless network:** (first choice)

- I will use a wireless router that is not connected to the internet. My PC and Mac will be connected to each other wirelessly. I can then connect the PC to the internet via a wired network, but then the Mac will not have internet access as its wireless card is already in use. In this case, could I stream internet access from the PC to the Mac via the wireless network? Or could I buy a USB wireless card for the Mac so that it can connect to both my private network and the dorm network?

**If I build a private wired network:** (second choice)

- Then both the PC and the Mac will connect to the internet wirelessly, which means I cannot take advantage of the faster download speeds.

Comment: Why not use a router to connect to the internet and connect your PCs to the router? You could even use a old PC and run a linux on it to act as a router, if you don't care for the time consumed for configuration and the cost for the power the system uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an actual wireless *router* (not an access point), your other devices' MAC addresses aren't exposed to the outside. It will appear (almost) as though there's just one device: Your router.

Comment: Thanks for this. Using a router was my first thought, but the Residential IT people argued that it would not work due to the MAC address issue. I should have not trusted them (they were very anal about setting up a private network within the dorm) and gone ahead and done it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wireless router. Only the router's MAC address is exposed on the network. I'm at UC Berkeley and we have a similar network setup. I recently purchased a [Netgear WNDR3700](http://www.netgear.com/products/service-providers/routers-and-gateways/gigabit-ethernet-routers-gateways/WNDR3700.aspx) to connect to my wired network. I use [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware so I can expose my local network DNS-SD (aka Bonjour) services to the rest of the dorm network. This works really well for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up getting a Cisco/Linksys E2000 router to use with DD-WRT. Hopefully it'll just work and simplify my life. Go bears!